# How can I take out the overhead door window glass for cleaning?

Tags: repair, doors, garage, glass

The space between the glass and frame are full of bug things. How can I take out the window glass? I searched several YouTube videos. They are either simple screw mount or by clipper molding. What about mines? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: don't take out the glass ... take out the decorative covers ... they are flexible and slip out ... you can also leave them out for more light inside the garage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole window assembly is snap inserted from OUTSIDE of the garage door.

They might be held in place by magnets. Use a screwdriver to find out if there are magnets along the frame.

Push in the corners from inside towards outside.

[image: window inside]

[image: window outside]

Comment: I recall now that you're (almost) right. It's just the overlay that pops off. See https://www.clopaydoor.com/blog/post/2010/07/02/how-to-clean-garage-door-windows.

Comment: @YRJ you are welcome, now check my Answer as complete, otherwise it stays open forever.